# Algorithm for change expression to three address code

Tags: algorithm

I have expressions in the following syntax:

```
exp := cons | 
       var | 
       exp binop exp | 
       unop exp
```

where binop is binary operators like plus and unop is unary operators like negetive. and I want to convert them to [three address code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code) form.

for example: expression `3 + a * 7 * (3 + (~4))` will be:

```
__var_1 = ~ 4;
__var_2 = 3 + __var_1;
__var_3 = 7 * __var_2;
__var_4 = a * __var_3;
__var_5 = 3 + __var_4;
```

The language is not matter and only algorithm is important for me.

Comment: What's your question again? Do you want to know how to optimally transform the expression into three-address-code? The above does looks quite plausible at first glance - at least if you don't optimize to reduce the number of registers used.

Comment: Only the algorithm of transformation or a code, Optimization is not necessary. for example something like this: `first Make a tree to represent expression, then traverse post order, then .... ` or by a recursive function.

Comment: If you have access to the *Dragon Book* there's a pretty substantial treatise on *syntax-directed translation* which is a popular technique still, at least for a compiler's front-end which generates intermediate code. The back-end (optimizer etc.) is a different story. Otherwise, search for "syntax directed translation three address code". You'll find a host of information on how to translate your above grammar into three address code.